# Passing a drawable between Activities image looks Stretched

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-intent

I am building an app in which I am having a listview with imageview and textview and when I click on a list item I would like to pass the name and the image to the other activity.

I have managed to do this but when I passed the image in the other activity the image looks streched. How to fix this?

I used Android Asset Studio to make the images I downloaded to be available at all sizes.

In the listview the image looks fine but in the other activity the image looks stretched.

Here is my code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<ListaAdapterNext> adapter = new MySpecialAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(NextActivity.this, ListItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", skonakia.get(position).getItemNextName().toString());
                intent.putExtra("icon", skonakia.get(position).getImageNextId());
                intent.putExtra("usage", skonakia.get(position).getItemUsage());
                intent.putExtra("description", skonakia.get(position).getItemDescription());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

here I send the drawable id to the other activity

here is how I receive them:

```
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
        TextView usage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.usage);
        String fetchedText = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        String fetchedDescription = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
        String fetchedUsage = getIntent().getStringExtra("usage");
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewListItem);
        Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(getIntent().getIntExtra("icon", -1));
        iv.setImageDrawable(image);
        tv.setText(fetchedDescription);
        usage.setText(fetchedUsage);
        getActionBar().setTitle(fetchedText);
```

And here are the 2 layouts I use for the listview and the other activity when someone clicks on a listitem

ListView Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewListItem"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_app" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ListItemClicked Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.kostas.myapplication.ListItemActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewListItem"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/usage"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/usage"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buy"
            android:id="@+id/buyButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you convert the drawable to a bytearray pass the bytearray to the intent via put and then get your drawable back

Comment: Yes file KostasMatrix... Use the bitmap factory...i think it should do the job...give it a try

Answer (score 2):

> Note: Prior to JELLY_BEAN, this function would not correctly retrieve
>   the final configuration density when the resource ID passed here is an
>   alias to another Drawable resource. This means that if the density
>   configuration of the alias resource is different than the actual
>   resource, the density of the returned Drawable would be incorrect,
>   resulting in bad scaling. To work around this, you can instead
>   retrieve the Drawable through TypedArray.getDrawable. Use
>   Context.obtainStyledAttributes with an array containing the resource
>   ID of interest to create the TypedArray.

[getDrawable(int id)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable(int))

Could this be your problem?

Comment: ok i will try that but i dont think that this is the problemm